FTP: For what it is used for, why its URLs sometimes begin with 'http://', and its modern alternatives
There are three questions here.
If I understand correctly, FTP URL syntax begins with ftp://:
ftp://[user[:password]@]host[:port]/[url-path]

But if I open the GNU Emacs download page and click the "main FTP server" link there, this will open the http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs URL, which begins with http:// and not ftp://. Why is it so?
The second question: What is the purpose to use FTP? If I have a website and I want to share some files, and I don't want or don't have time to create an HTML page for this, I can simply upload them to somewhere like https://my.blog/uploads, and that's it, isn't?
And are there modern "mainstream" alternatives to FTP?

FTP is nowadays considered a legacy protocol. It is clear text, requires two TCP connections on different ports and bolting on TLS encryption did not really fix any/all issues surrounding FTP.
In the past it made sense to link from web sites to FTP download sites with a ftp:// URI  because many/most web browsers had a native FTP client built in and/or otherwise people would have had an FTP client installed. People could easily open such links and download (large) files.
Since 2021 when both Firefox and Chrome dropped FTP and others followed most browsers don't support FTP anymore.
Nowadays most downloads can easily be handled with a web browser and over HTTP(S).
It makes much more sense for a web page to link to a secure web server, which supports HTTPS and that serves the same directory tree with downloads that the FTP server would expose than link to a ftp:// URI that people using web browsers can't open.
People who really want to use FTP can manually open the FTP site in their FTP client.

A web browser is not a good file manager and using it for downloading more than a handful files cumbersome. FTP and a  FTP client is/was much better at recursively up- and/or downloading  complete directory structures. That can be handled over HTTP(S) as well but usually requires much more complex web/browser apps to run both client and server side to give a satisfactory user experience

Some FTP servers provide additional HTTP access - those a very different protocols, however.
FTP stands for file transfer protocol and that is its purpose exactly. FTP predates HTTP by two decades and even the Internet by more than one.
